# Linking Excel ComboBox with List Based on Independent Cell

Tags: excel, combobox

I'm attempting to add items to an Excel Combobox, based on the value of an independent cell. So what I need is an IF statement, obviously.

So it should look something like this, (note: C1 is the independent cell):

```
IF C1 = "3"
AddItem "One"
AddItem "Two"
ELSE IF C1 = "4"
AddItem "Three"
.etc.
```

The problem is that I don't know how to properly link the ComboBox such that it knows when the independent cell value has changed to trigger a clearing of existing items in the ComboBox and repopulation of new items.

Comment: `when the independent cell value has changed to trigger` It sounds like you're looking for the Worksheet_Change event.

Comment: Tip: since you are only checking one cell, you should use the `Case` method rather the `If` method

Comment: @tigeravatar Yeah that's what I decided to go with. Also, do you know how I would access the current selected ComboBox value in the sheet itself so that I could use it in a formula?

Comment: @John You'll need to define the cell as the LinkedCell in the combobox properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code needs to go on the sheet with your target cell `C1`

Every time your cell `C1` is changed, it will force the code you insert to execute. *In this case*, it will force an update to your dropdown list.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C1"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        'YOUR CODE HERE

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit 1: (How to add items to a combo box?)**

Add an ActiveX Control Combo Box

> Developer Tab > Insert > ActiveX Controls > ComboBox

You can then refer to your Combo box inside your loop as follows:

```
Combobox1.Clear             'To clear
ComboBox1.AddItem "Text"    'To Add
```

Comment: Do you know how I would access the current selected ComboBox value in the sheet itself so that I could use it in a formula?

Comment: Link it to a cell

Comment: In VBE, Go into design mode > right click on your combo box > Properties > Add a cell to "LinkedCell" like *A1* .... Then you can just refer to A1 in your formula.